# Is there any feature where the Apps in the Windows Store update themselves when there is an update?

Tags: windows-8, automatic-update, windows-store

Is it possible for the apps in the Windows Store to update themselves whenever an update is found? This could be very useful as one cannot go to AppStore every time and look for updates.

Auto Update of the Apps would be a wonderful feature.

Answer (score 8):

Windows Store provides an auto-update feature. To enable this:

- Launch Windows Store
- Bring up the Charms bar by moving the pointer to top right edge of the screen (or hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- Click on Settings → App Updates

[image]

- Enable the Auto Updates option

[image]

---

As for the actual update - no there isn't  a way you can have the app update automatically install.

Comment: This is a great feature except it doesn't automatically install the updates either.